# How to program three app sections

Tags: java, android

I want to have three sections in my app, all with three buttons that make it so that you can travel to any of the three sections. I tried doing this with activities, but it didn't work, are there any other ways to do this? Some people say that you can use fragments, but I don't understand how. Here's my activities code:

**Section 1:**

```
SectionTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Splashscreen.class);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.swipe_right, R.anim.swipe_out_left);
        }
    });

SectionThree.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Intervals_and_Chords.class);
           startActivity(i);
           overridePendingTransition(R.anim.swipe_right, R.anim.swipe_out_left);
        }
    });
```

**Section 2:**

```
SectionOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.swipe_left, R.anim.swipe_out_right);
        }
    });


SectionThree.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent toInterval = new Intent(Splashscreen.this, Intervals_and_Chords.class);
            startActivity(toInterval);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.swipe_right, R.anim.swipe_out_left);
        }
    });
```

**Section 3:**

```
SectionTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.swipe_left, R.anim.swipe_out_right);
        }
    });


SectionOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.swipe_left, R.anim.swipe_out_right);
        }
    });
```

The problem with my activities code is that when you go from section one to section two then to section three and then try to go back from section three to section one it brings you to section two! I think it's because of the finish(); in section three, it doesn't know what section it's supposed to go to, and since it came from section two it always goes back there.

Comment: Check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47241565/1880899

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Android Fragment** are made to accomplish such design purposes.
you can use [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html) in conjunction of [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).

Below are some example you can go through with :

1. [example1](https://segunfamisa.com/posts/bottom-navigation-view-android)
2. [example 2](http://droidmentor.com/bottomnavigationview-with-viewpager-android/)

Comment: I tried doing this but from what I understand you can only flip through three fragments, I want to flip from my main activity (home) to two other fragments.