# Reusable views?

Tags: android, android-fragments, view, bottomnavigationview

I'm new to Android development, but I have quite some bit of Swing/WPF(C#) GUI experience. What I'm trying to do is the following:

I have a `BottomNavigationView` with 3 separate views. Each view is implemented as a fragment that is shown/ hidden in the MainActivity java code through a `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`:

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.one:
                findViewById(R.id.one).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                findViewById(R.id.two).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                findViewById(R.id.threee).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return true;
    // ... and so on
```

My problem is that a part of the interface of two of the fragments is identical and made of a set of `EditText` and `ImageButton`. So I thought of creating something re-usable instead of doubling the code. My options are to make a fragment inside a fragment (but around the internet I saw that this is not advisable) or to make a re-usable view (https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html, https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html). What is the best way to do it? I'd like to have a xml layout with a connected java code, where I can listen to the interactions with the `EditText` and the `Buttons` and act accordingly. Maybe I'm biased by my WPF experience but I'm trying to make it like a xaml + codebehind, which may not be the correct way to tackle the problem when building Android apps.

Comment: If you want the same methodS to do in the same Views in Java code then declare static methods to do the same thing according to your application logic but I have given an answer on how you can reuse Views but if that is not what you want comment in my question and explain what I will edit my answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to define a separate XML layout for a View that you will use more than once and

**In XML**
You will use the `<include>` Tag inside your layout like

```
 ...
<include layout="@layout/your_frequent_used_layout"/>

<TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/hello"
          android:padding="10dp" />
....
```

More information [here in the documentation training!](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

**In Java**
For Java side If you want to get a certain view and add to your current layout you will need a layout Inflater and then add to your `View` like this in your activity (*In your fragment consider contexts if it throws any errors*)

1st Option:

```
View view = null;
LayoutInflater inflater = 
(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_reusable_view, null);
your_main_root_view.addView(view);
```

2nd Option:

```
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_reusable_view, null);
your_main_root_view.addView(child);
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Is it possible to a have a class where I can listen to the events raised by these EditText and Buttons? Or should I implement the listeners in the MainView?

Comment: Yeah make a class with an interface and method and implement the interfaces in your mainView classes.

Comment: Give me the whole idea so I can get it! and answer it!

Comment: I am glad you solved your problem @Marco **Happy Coding!**.

Answer (score 2):

As per your code in the question, you are just showing/hiding the views present in the layout.
So, firstly I would suggest using **BottomNavigationView** in conjunction with a **ViewPager** and creating independent Fragments for every navigation item.
This article demonstrates how to get started
http://droidmentor.com/bottomnavigationview-with-viewpager-android/

Secondly, for all the fragments that contain common items, you will create an abstract **BaseFragment** that will manage all the common logic.
Extend this abstract fragment to create your individual fragments and Inflate the unique layouts.

**fragment_base.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--- Your Common Elements Here --->

    <!--- Unique Elements will get inserted here --->

</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_nav_unique1.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--- Unique Elements For the Nav View Item --->

</LinearLayout>
```

**BaseFragment.java**

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    // Get Layout resource id of the Individual Fragments
    protected abstract int layoutResourceId();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the base layout
        LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_base, container, false);

        // Inflate the unique layouts and add them to the view    
        LinearLayout uniqueView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId(), null);
        view.addView(uniqueView);

        // Return view
        return view;
    }

    //--- Manage all the Common Elements here ---

}
```

**FirstFragment.java**

```
public class FirstFragment extends BaseFragment {
    @Override
    protected int layoutResourceId() {
        // Return the resource of the unique layout
        return R.layout.fragment_nav_unique1;
    }

    //--- Manage all the Unique Elements here ---

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CustomView is the way to go for this. Not only you can use the same layout file in this but can also define similar interactions with this view in your custom view implementation.